# Vim YouCompleteMe plugin - don't download clang

Tags: vim, plugins, clang, youcompleteme

I want to install and use the YouCompleteMe Plugin for Vim. However, a part of the installation implies downloading clang 3.7, which is already a part of my current Ubuntu installation. Generally, wasting space on multiple versions of the same application on my file system is something I disregard, but now I'm also running dual-boot and don't have that much space left for a "casual" downloaded copy of clang just to make use of this plugin.

How can I make the YouCompleteMe to make use of the installation/libraries I already have, if possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your YCM install method, you will have to specify something like:

`--system-libclang --system-boost`

…as arguments to the `install.py` command.

Note that the YCM install [docs](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#full-installation-guide) strongly discourage the usage of `system-libclang`.